# Add jittered data points to lattice xYplot with error bars

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I'm trying to plot error bars overlaid on jittered raw data points using [xYplot from package Hmisc](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/Hmisc/docs/xYplot). Seemed straightforward to just call a function within `xYplot` using `panel.stripplot`. It works, but there is a strange glitch - I can't 'jitter' the data plotted with `panel.stripplot`. Let me illustrate my point:

```
library(reshape2)
library(Hmisc)
data(iris)
#get error bars
d <- melt(iris, id=c("Species"), measure=c("Sepal.Length"))
X <- dcast(d, Species ~ variable, mean)
SD <- dcast(d, Species ~ variable, sd)
SE = SD[,2]/1#this is wrong on purpose, to plot larger error bars
Lo = X[,2]-SE
Hi = X[,2]+SE
fin <- data.frame(X,Lo=Lo,Hi=Hi)
#plot the error bars combined with raw data points
quartz(width=5,height=7)
xYplot(Cbind(Sepal.Length, Lo, Hi) ~ numericScale(Species), fin,  
       type=c("p"), ylim=c(4,8),lwd=3, col=1,
       scales = list(x = list(at=1:3, labels=levels(d$Species))),
       panel = function(x, y, ...) { 
         panel.xYplot(x, y, ...)
         panel.stripplot(d$Species, d$value, jitter.data = TRUE, cex=0.2, ...)
  }
)
```

Which results in:

[image]

As you can see, the points are lined up vertically with the error bars, why I would like them to be slightly offset in horizontal plain. I tried to tweak `factor` and `amount` parameters in the `panel.stripplot` but it doesn't change it. Any suggestions? Solutions with lattice-only please, preferably using `xYplot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `horizontal=FALSE`:

```
panel.stripplot(d$Species, d$value,                                         
                          jitter.data = TRUE, cex=0.2,horizontal=FALSE, ...)
```

Internally is just a call to :

```
panel.xyplot(d$Species, d$value, cex=0.2,jitter.x=TRUE, ...)
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Do you know how to control the amount of jittering?

Comment: there is argument `amount`. Internnally it uses base function `jitter`  For example `jitter(1:10,amount=10)`.